# PHP for() loop with links

Tags: php, for-loop

**What I'm trying to do:** create a numbered list of pictures with links to each picture. The list numbers are not consecutive.

**Variables:**

- `$image->number` - gives the first number;
- `$image->next_pid` - gives the "next link";
- `$image->total` - gives the last number;

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$list_first = $image->number;
$list_last = $image->total;
for ($list_first = 1; $list_first <= $list_last; $list_first++) {
    echo($list_first);
}
?>
```

**Problem:** this code lists the numbered list of pictures that I need. What I can't figure out is how to include the "next link" variable into the loop.

Example: `number` = 1; `next_pid` = link_ID2; `total` = 7. So the list will look like this: 1 (without link) 2 (with link_ID2) 3 (link_ID3) etc. until 7. The first picture doesn't have a link because it's already showing. Sorry for not being explicit enough.

You can view what I'm trying to do [here](http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/residential/rooftop-garden/). I've listed the other pictures in that gallery but without a link. It's a wordpress site and a plugin I'm using to display the pictures in each gallery. You can view on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/2b6jmS8s) the functions.php of that plugin.

Comment: Are the numbers sequential, or arbitrary?

Comment: Use a while loop instead. While the next one is not null...

Comment: Sequential (1,2,3,4 etc)

Comment: So this is like a pagination display, where `number` might contain 5, `total` might contain 10, and `next_pid` contains a link to the page that shows 11 - 15?

Comment: I've included an example in the post, hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Why does image 1 have no Next link? Surely it's 7 that shouldn't?

Comment: I thought it was clear but now I'm confused. Do you mean a [list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) of pictures or a main picture and a link to the others? There are more confusing things, could you provide an image or page that behaves similar to what you want please?

Comment: And can you also include a `var_dump($image)`? Because I can't figure out what it structure might be.

Comment: First post updated, sorry for not being explicit enough.

Comment: Don't worry (;  
I've seen something in your page, apparently, the images are not consecutive, so you'd need an array with the given valid images, a script to check the directory or make your pages/images consecutive.

Comment: You're right, they are not consecutive and I need a script to check the current gallery for each image ID. This is too complicated for my knowledge, but thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This should do the trick.

```
<?php 

$list_last = $image->total;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $list_last; $i++)
  {
  if ($_GET['pid'] != $i) echo "<a href='http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/residential/rooftop-garden/15/?pid=".$i."'> ".$i." </a>";
  else echo $i;
  }
?>
```

The bit `$list_first = $image->number;` is of no use as you overwrite it shortly after in the for loop.

Added an extra line not to display a link for the current image.